# google maps for Android, if run this code it will only latitude and longitude value but should not display any value

Tags: android

google map coding

```
package com.project.friendtracker;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location; 
import android.location.LocationListener; 
import android.location.LocationManager; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; 
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.app.Dialog; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileWriter; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar; 
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil; 
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

public class MainActivity1 extends FragmentActivity implements
LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 900000, 300, this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

        try {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String time = df.format(c.getTime());
            File file = new File("/sdcard/longlat.txt");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true);
            writer.append(time+"--"+"Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude +"--");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 String importError = e.getMessage();
              //   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), importError,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }   



    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    //@Override     /*public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {       //
Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
present.        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);       return
true;   }*/

}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymapexample1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mymapexample1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mymapexample1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mymapexample1.MainActivity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB6DYafop-H2vkJo6eq2qhqkeXjiBaeAqI"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
     </RelativeLayout> but this code give map value,only give latitude and longtitude values.
```

Comment: i am only write this code,if i run this code it give only longtitude and lattitude values,it should not display map view,give some solutions

Answer (score 0):

Google had provided some new code for to get Location data. Try with it, it will work fantastic as I have did work with it.

Follow below link, it is very useful tutorial.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html